# Upgrading to gradle plugin 3.2.1 and SDK 28 fails

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin

When I'm trying to update to the android gradle plugin v 3.2.1 and compile SDK 28, I get the error/stacktrace below on our buildserver (debian), on Mac OS, this works fine.

Old working configuration:

- classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
- compileSdkVersion 27
- buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
- gradle wrapper 4.6

New broken configuration

- classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
- compileSdkVersion 28
- buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
- gradle wrapper 4.10.2

Does anyone have a clue what could go wrong here?

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected file collection to contain exactly one file, however, it contains no files.
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:73)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$400(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:54)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:200)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:110)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:68)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:687)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:140)
at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:62)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:41)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:274)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.configureBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:182)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:141)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:77)
at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:74)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:154)
at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:38)
at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:96)
at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:74)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:50)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:79)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:50)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at     org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:86)
at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:187)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:184)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.stepEvaluationListener(DefaultProject.java:1418)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:193)
... 91 more
Caused by: com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.ExternalApiUsageException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected file collection to contain exactly one file, however, it contains no files.
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApiObjectFactory.create(ApiObjectFactory.java:137)
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:772)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$4(BasePlugin.java:646)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.CrashReporting$afterEvaluate$1.execute(crash_reporting.kt:37)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.CrashReporting$afterEvaluate$1.execute(crash_reporting.kt)
at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1$1.run(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:155)
at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.reapply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:58)
at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:152)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:149)
at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:91)
at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:80)
at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
... 101 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected file collection to contain exactly one file, however, it contains no files.
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.getSingleFile(AbstractFileCollection.java:65)
at org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection$getSingleFile.call(Unknown Source)
at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.FabricTaskBuilder.crashlyticsStoreDeobs(FabricTaskBuilder.groovy:144)
at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.FabricTaskBuilder$crashlyticsStoreDeobs$0.call(Unknown Source)
at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin.attachPostCompileTasks(CrashlyticsPlugin.groovy:493)
at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin.this$2$attachPostCompileTasks(CrashlyticsPlugin.groovy)
at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin.addPluginTasks(CrashlyticsPlugin.groovy:248)
at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin.this$2$addPluginTasks(CrashlyticsPlugin.groovy)
at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:479)
at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:191)
at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:78)
at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin$_addPluginTasksToApplicationVariantsIn_closure2.doCall(CrashlyticsPlugin.groovy:93)
at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:155)
at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:106)
at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$WrappedConfigureAction.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:167)
at org.gradle.internal.ImmutableActionSet$SetWithFewActions.execute(ImmutableActionSet.java:285)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:244)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:233)
at com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.addVariant(AppExtension.java:87)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApiObjectFactory.create(ApiObjectFactory.java:134)
... 120 more
```

build.gradle snippet from /app module

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: "spoon"
apply plugin: "dexguard"
apply plugin: "io.fabric"
apply plugin: "jacoco"
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

def fullVersion
if (project.hasProperty("realVersionName") && project.realVersionName)     {
    // versionName generated by the Jenkinsfile
    fullVersion = project.realVersionName
} else {
    // Fallback for local builds
    fullVersion = projectVersion + ".1"
}

def versionCodeNr = Integer.parseInt(projectVersionCode)

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode versionCodeNr
    versionName fullVersion
    applicationId projectApplicationId

    renderscriptTargetApi 28
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
    }

}

signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file("../keystore/debug.keystore")
    }

    release {
        storeFile file("../keystore/release.keystore")
        storePassword RELEASE_KEYSTORE_STORE_PASSWORD
        keyAlias RELEASE_KEYSTORE_KEY_ALIAS
        keyPassword RELEASE_KEYSTORE_KEY_PASSWORD
    }
}

buildTypes {

    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        ext.enableCrashlytics = false
    }

    report.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
    report {
        testCoverageEnabled true
        matchingFallbacks = ['debug']
    }

    client {
        debuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug

        proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile("...")

        ...
    }

    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release

        ...
    }
}

testOptions {
    unitTests {
        includeAndroidResources true
    }
}

compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.8
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
}
}

ext {
    supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    glideVersion = "4.7.1"
    daggerVersion = "2.13"
    ...
}

dependencies {
    // Google dependencies
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3"

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0"

    //noinspection GradleDependency
implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5"

    // Glide
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glideVersion"
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:$glideVersion"
    //kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glideVersion"

    // Dagger
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"

}

apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

Comment: Do you have a multi-module project? Do you use Instant App?

Comment: It's indeed a multi module project (all modules share the same version of the properties above). It's not an instant app

Comment: Hm... maybe you use Kotlin or custom BuildType? Can you add `build.gradle` code for app module?

Comment: I updated the question with the build.gradle file for /app, it's indeed a kotlin app with extra buildtypes

Comment: This is probably related to the Gradle plugin update from 3.1.4 to 3.2.1, because I am seeing the same error with API 27. On MacOS.

Comment: Guys, did you get it working?

Comment: I am also facing this issue with io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.1 [stackoverflow.com/questions/58416694/…. Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4` and it will work.

Comment: It's a temporary solution but it works indeed. I've a mail thread running with the guys of Firebase support, I'll keep you updated

Comment: One downside with this is that you will not have access to the features introduced in 1.26 and above, as seen here: https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin. Quentin, thank you for reporting the bug to Firebase.

Comment: I am also facing this issue with io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.1 [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58416694/exception-when-using-io-fabric-toolsgradle1-27-1]. Any other solution than downgrading version?